# multirow SQL Update not working as expected - SELECT result different from UPDATE result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-update, inner-join

I have a multiple row update query that is not working like I expect it to. The `JOIN` condition is adhered to in the `SELECT` statement, but not in the `UPDATE` statement.

In other words: I changed 1 row, the `SELECT` query shows only 1 result (as expected). I convert the query to an `UPDATE` statement and run it - all rows in the table are changed to the same value - the `JOIN` condition is totally ignored.

I thought it was due to a table variable, so I used a temp table and get the same results. I verified my `JOIN` condition is comparing the same datatype (it's an `INNER JOIN`). I'm at a loss as to why this will not work

```
SELECT 
    (o.SubTotal - o.OrderDiscounts) AS OrderSubTotal, 
    t.CommRate *  (o.SubTotal - o.OrderDiscounts) AS CommDue, 
    'MODIFIED' AS "Status" 
FROM
    bvc_Order o 
INNER JOIN 
    #tbl t ON o.OrderNumber = t.OrderNumber
```

Converted to an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE AffiliateComm
SET [OrderSubtotal] = (o.SubTotal - o.OrderDiscounts), 
    [CommDue] = t.CommRate * (o.SubTotal - o.OrderDiscounts),  
    [Status] = 'MODIFIED'  
FROM 
    bvc_Order o 
INNER JOIN 
    #tbl t ON o.OrderNumber = t.OrderNumber
```

I've done the same query with a table variable - (select works, update always updates all rows & ignores JOIN condition) no joy.

Stranger still, if I put a `WHERE` clause on the end, it is IGNORED!
As in

```
WHERE o.OrderNumber = t.OrderNumber
```

I've done queries like these before and never had this problem.

The output of the `SELECT` query (as an example when 1 row needs changing)

```
OrderSubTotal   CommDue  Status
----------------------------------
1285.20         38.56    MODIFIED
```

WHEN I run the update query:

> (1 row(s) affected) <-This is the temp table (or variable) having 1 row inserted as it should CORRECT
>
> (5 row(s) affected) <- This is the INCORRECT number of rows affected by the UPDATE (should be 1)

Is there a setting in SQL Server 2012 that is wrong? If you inner join a table with 1 row, it's not possible to have MORE than 1 row as a result set, right?

I'm baffled.

Comment: What is AffiliateComm? It's not in any of your join criteria.

Comment: ^ I was just looking at old queries similarly built - you're right, AffiliateComm is not in the join condition (this must be the problem - producing ambiguity), but needs to be. I'm rearranging this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
UPDATE ac
    SET [OrderSubtotal] = (o.SubTotal - o.OrderDiscounts),
        [CommDue] = t.CommRate*(o.SubTotal - o.OrderDiscounts),
        [Status] = 'MODIFIED'  
FROM AffiliateComm ac INNER JOIN
     bvc_Order o
     ON ac.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber INNER JOIN
     #tbl t
     ON o.OrderNumber = t.OrderNumber ;
```

In other words, `AffiliateComm` needs to be joined into the other tables, somehow.  Otherwise, all rows in `AffiliateComm` will be updated, I believe with the same value.  I made up an `AffiliateId` for the above query.

Comment: I'm a Space Cadet!  I changed the join condition to the following - it works now.  

FROM bvc_Order o INNER JOIN AffiliateComm ac ON ac.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber 
  INNER JOIN #tbl t ON t.OrderNumber = ac.OrderNumber

Answer (score 1):

In your update:

```
    UPDATE AffiliateComm
    SET [OrderSubtotal]=(o.SubTotal - o.OrderDiscounts), [CommDue]=t.CommRate*(o.SubTotal - o.OrderDiscounts),[Status]='MODIFIED'  
    FROM bvc_Order o 
    INNER JOIN #tbl t 
        ON o.OrderNumber = t.OrderNumber
```

You tell sql server to update a table called AffiliateComm. However, this table is not included in your join.

Not knowing the schema of this table, i can only guess at whata right, possibly something like:

```
    UPDATE a
    SET [OrderSubtotal]=(o.SubTotal - o.OrderDiscounts), [CommDue]=t.CommRate*(o.SubTotal - o.OrderDiscounts),[Status]='MODIFIED'  
    FROM AffiliateComm A
    INNER JOIN bvc_Order o 
       ON o.OrderNumber = a.OrderNumber
    INNER JOIN #tbl t 
        ON o.OrderNumber = t.OrderNumbe
```